# Storing large Number of images

Tags: android, image

I have lots of Images in my app right now i put all in drawable. images have been pre-compressed/optimized for mobile viewing. 
(But I want these all images in sdcard and use that location instead of drawable. because of large amount of images)

One of my requirements is that I be able to provide offline access for users. I am wondering what would be the most efficient way

of storing a large amount of images (around four hundred-several thousand)

So My Plan is  that I will Store all images in sdcard(by making a folder in it) and now store link of these
images in data base Table.

So App first fetch image path from DB Table  then fetch file from sdcard and display it.

But my problem is Where should i put these images while developing app.

(Should i put all my images in drawable and then copy it sdcard programitically and then start using that location !!! )

1) How to store all these images in sd-card at the time of development of application. ?
2) So when  I will deploy my app these all images should available inside package ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have large number of images, then on first start of the app, download images from a remote location and store them on your SD card and build your db table. It doesn't make sense to have them in your drawables and then copy them to your SD card.

EDIT

If you want to copy a image from drawable and store it on SD card then here's how you could do it -

You have to first convert the drawable to a bitmap object.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.filenameindrawable);
```

Now store it on your sd card using FileOutputStream

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file on sd card");
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is not the recommended way though.

Comment: I apologies for my weak English, I am not downloading images from internet. I have to put all my images in my app package at the time of diployement, and when i install app then images should be store in some directory and that directory path with images name is already store in db. So how to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want images on SD card and not in drawable folder? You can just keep everything in drawable folder and then get it using R.drawable.filename? That way you don't have to maintain a DB.

Comment: then whats recommended way?

Comment: Like I said earlier, if you have it in drawable then keep it in drawable. Why do you want to move it to SD card?

Comment: There Are two reason to move images from drawable to sd card. 1)App may be install in phone memory so it takes too much memory used 2) Application may be crash if i  storing large number of images drawable. Thats why I am about to stor images in sd card and my app size will be about 50 MB just because of images.

Comment: It is not possible to move images from drawable to sd card. You can make a copy of it but you cannot remove it from drawable folder of your apk file. So even if you copy files from drawable to sd card it is not possible to reduce the app size once it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

storing application images on SD card is not a good idea. Because if some one don't have sd card or removed sd card after your app installation those images will not be available for uor app. and any one can accessthose images stored in sd card. so bettor to store those images on Internal Filesystem of your app at the first launch of the app by download images from a remote location and store them on your SD card/Internalfilesystem and update your db table.

Comment: Thanks raj, But I have all these images in my drawable folder and i am not downloading it from any where, it will reside in app package at the time of installation of app. So Let me know where to put these all. drawable or somewhere else.?

Comment: When I will install apk, All images should be copied into sd card.? How do i Do this functionality.?